# Booting Kali Linux from USB from a MacBook Pro running on Windows 7

Tags: linux, macos, boot, reboot

I wiped OS X from my computer a while ago and started using Windows 7 instead (for school and work reasons). I am trying to install Kali Linux on my computer on a separate partition. I have tried too many times to get this to work, but I am determined to get it right.

I have used these two different programs to try to make the USB bootable:

- ISO to USB
- UnetBootIn

They have worked before on other computers but can't seem to work on mine.

I try to reboot the computer and look for booting options on the screen - but Mac computers run on EFI, not BIOS. So most of the recommendations that I find on the internet don't really work.

Before I wiped Mac OS from my hard drive I tried using rEFIt to host multiple partitions and operating systems but I'm not sure how I would install that for a Mac, from a Windows.

Any help would be very, very appreciated.

Comment: Not tried yet, buy Kali 1.08 is supposed to support EFI boot: http://www.kali.org/kali-linux-releases/

Comment: You may try bios function (if available) and manually boot the appropriate EFI file from your USB drive. Access your bios and look for bootoptions or similar.

Answer (score 0):

First off, to solve your EFI issue, you should use rEFInd, not rEFIt as the latter is no longer supported.  Here is the link to manually install it on Windows:

http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#windows

Unfortunately, I'm not running Windows (Mac OS X and Kali on an external USB HDD), so I cannot troubleshoot easily if you run into issues, but if you follow the directions very closely, you should be fine.  Let me know if you're not.

Secondly, there are instructions for creating a bootable live USB kali drive at the official site, here:

http://docs.kali.org/installation/kali-linux-live-usb-install

Again, no Windows here so give it a shot per the instructions and report back if you have issues.  Also let me know if you're successful as well!  Good luck!

**Most importantly: backups, backups, backups!**